# Fitting a Support Vector Classifier in scikit-learn with image data produces error

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to train an SVC classifier for image data. Yet, when I run this code:

```python
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)
classifier.fit(train_set, train_set_labels)
```

I get this error:

```python
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I produced the images into an array with Matplotlib: `plt.imread(image)`.

The error seems like it's not in an array, yet when I check the types of the data and the labels they're both lists (I manually add to a list for the labels data):

```python
print(type(train_set))
print(type(train_set_labels))

<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
```

If I do a `plt.imshow(items[0])` then the image shows correctly in the output.

I also called `train_test_split` from `scikit-learn`:

```python
train_set, test_set = train_test_split(items, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Example input:

```python
train_set[0]

array([[[212, 134,  34],
    [221, 140,  48],
    [240, 154,  71],
    ..., 
    [245, 182,  51],
    [235, 175,  43],
    [242, 182,  50]],

   [[230, 152,  51],
    [222, 139,  47],
    [236, 147,  65],
    ..., 
    [246, 184,  49],
    [238, 179,  43],
    [245, 186,  50]],

   [[229, 150,  47],
    [205, 122,  28],
    [220, 129,  46],
    ..., 
    [232, 171,  28],
    [237, 179,  35],
    [244, 188,  43]],

   ..., 
   [[115, 112, 103],
    [112, 109, 102],
    [ 80,  77,  72],
    ..., 
    [ 34,  25,  28],
    [ 55,  46,  49],
    [ 80,  71,  74]],

   [[ 59,  56,  47],
    [ 66,  63,  56],
    [ 48,  45,  40],
    ..., 
    [ 32,  23,  26],
    [ 56,  47,  50],
    [ 82,  73,  76]],

   [[ 29,  26,  17],
    [ 41,  38,  31],
    [ 32,  29,  24],
    ..., 
    [ 56,  47,  50],
    [ 59,  50,  53],
    [ 84,  75,  78]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Example label:

```python
 train_set_labels[0]

 'Picasso'
```

I'm not sure what step I'm missing to get the data in the form that the classifier needs in order to train it. Can anyone see what may be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are receiving:

```
 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence,
```

normally results when you are trying to put a list somewhere that a single value is required. This would suggest to me that your train_set is made up of a list of multidimensional elements, although you do state that your inputs are lists. Would you be able to post an example of your inputs and labels?

UPDATE
Yes, it's as I thought. The first element of your training data, train_set[0], corresponds to a long list (I can't tell how long), each element of which consists of a list of 3 elements. You are therefore calling the classifier on a list of lists of lists, when the classifier requires a list of lists (m rows corresponding to the number of training examples with each row made up of a list of n features). What else is in your train_set array? Is the full data set in train_set[0]? If so, you would need to create a new array with each element corresponding to each of the subelements of train_set[0], and then I believe your code should run, although I am not too familiar with that classifier. Alternatively you could try running the classifier with train_set[0].

UPDATE 2

I don't have experience with scikit-learn.svc so I wouldn't be able to tell you what the best way of preprocessing the data in order for it to be acceptable to the algorithm, but one method would be to do as I said previously and for each element of train_set, which is composed of lists of lists, would be to recurse through and place all the elements of sublist into the list above. For example

```
new_train_set = []
    for i in range(len(train_set)):
        for j in range(len(train_set[i]):
        new_train_set.append([train_set[i,j])
```

I would then train with new_train_set and the training labels.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting to add something to it! I updated the question with the examples. Hope it helps!

Comment: `train_set[0]` is data from one image that I got from the `plt.imread()` function. Is that not the correct format?

Comment: Looks like you're on to something! Ran it with `train_set[0]` and it gives this error: `ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.` Though, it still seems odd that if I do a `plt.imshow(test_set_[0])` it shows the image correctly.

Comment: In the nicest way possible, imshow is a different function from svm, one shows an image, one learns statistical patterns from a set of training data, of which an image is one example, and hence they have different requirement. Imshow is expecting data in the format that you present to it, scikitlearn.svm is not!

Comment: Can you mark as answered please? If not, can I help further?

Comment: You got me on the right track! I found this [article](http://remote-sensing.eu/image-classification-with-python/) and saw this code to reshape my image data: `new_data = data.shape[0] * data.shape[1], data.shape[2]`. With that, I can now fit the classifier and predict on it! The accuracy isn't very good, but it'd be fun to optimize. Thanks!

Comment: Great! This was my first answer too so glad I could be of help. Interesting solution. I have found previously that scikit-learn is very particular about the dimensionality of input and that simply reshaping the data can solve the problem. And now on to the next step of ML for ya!